# Inserting in line using sed command

Tags: linux, sed, samba

The text in file looks like this:

```
[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        path = 
        browseable = 
        writable = yes
        valid users = %S
        valid users = MYDOMAIN\%S

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        browseable = no
        guest ok = no
        writable = no
        printable = yes
```

I want output as:

```
[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        path = /data
        browseable = yes
        writable = yes
        valid users = %S
        valid users = MYDOMAIN\%S

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        browseable = no
        guest ok = no
        writable = no
        printable = yes
```

I am using this command:

```
sed -i "\#path# s#.*#& /data#" file
```

It makes changes to everywhere in file where path is located.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

`sed '/path[ ]*=[ ]*$/s#$#/data#'`

On lines that have `path =`before the endline with any amount of whitespace, replace the endline, `$` with your replacement string.